# Execute SoapUI test on multi-threads

Tags: multithreading, soapui

I have a `SoapUI` test which uses an input file to read lines as input of requests. So there is a loop which reads data and execute request and write output to file. Response times are too long, so processing of this file should be done asynchronously, but I am not sure, how `SoapUI` can handle this. There is file attachment in `SOAP` requests, which is not handled by current version of `JMeter`.

Comment: Apache JMeter is great tool for such things.

Comment: Maybe yes, but this is written in `SoapUI` in `Groovy` and first of all `JMeter` can't handle file attachments in `SOAP` requests.

Comment: Not sure if it can or cannot, but SOAP is still just XML sent over HTTP, so you could simulate anything.

Comment: How many test case do you have in the suite? Have you tried `Parallel` execution?

Comment: It is only 1 testcase with 2 test steps. As I know it can't execute same test step in parallel, on multiple threads.

Comment: would you mind showing the groovy script you  are talking about in your earlier comment?

Comment: @Rao : It is a relly simple one, which reads a text file in a loop, line by line.

Comment: @plaidshirt, first thing is there is no async call in soapui, I believe. It would be great if can elaborate more on your use case. Any ways, can you check [this](https://github.com/nmrao/sample-soapui-projects/tree/master/hybridExecution) sample project which I created sometime ago and see if you can apply to your case?

Comment: @plaidshirt, have you got chance to check the link mentioned in the above comment? Did it help?

Comment: @Rao : So isn't it solved by SoapUI and should I implement it in code? Yes, I checked it out, but not sure how to read a text file line by line in multi thread and write output parallel in a output/log file. How is it possible to handle this situation in case of multi-threads?

Comment: @plaidshirt, soapui can run the test cases or suites in parallel.

Comment: @Rao : Could you show me please, how?

Comment: @plaidshirt, sure - please see this documentation of soapui which is explained there - https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html

Comment: It says: "This page contains information on standalone SoapUI Pro that has been replaced with ReadyAPI." I have only free/open source version of SoapUI.

Comment: @plaidshirt, please check the answer to see if that is helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the SoapUI's [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html) below, both test cases or test suites can be executed in `Parallel` mode.

> In the case of TestSuites and TestCases these can be executed either in sequence or parallell, as configured with the corresponding toolbar buttons.

[image]

In the above image, first one in the marked image stands for sequential execution and the second one (with multiple parallel arrows) stands for `Parallel` execution mode.

User can select either of the one before executing the tests.

Hope this helps.

Note that SOAPUI does not allows test steps to be executed in parallel. If you need any custom execution i.e., same test case and steps to be executed in Parallel, [here](https://github.com/nmrao/sample-soapui-projects/tree/master/hybridExecution) is sample project done for that. It can be used as reference and apply it to your case.

Answer (score 2):

I understood this question as requiring the ability to call a service asynchronously due to the time it takes to process.  So, by this, I mean SoapUI makes a request to a web service and instead of waiting for it, it carries on.  At some point later, SoapUI receives the response.

SoapUI can handle this, I haven't tried it myself, but when reading some guides recently, I noticed it can be done.

See....
[Blog Guide](http://blog.soasuitehandbook.org/test-asynchronous-service-from-soapui-chapter-12/)

[SoapUI Forum](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-do-I-consume-an-async-service-using-SoapUI/td-p/133521)

In short, it involves setting up a mock service to receive the response, which can then be validated.